# How to add Arabic contents to an english document in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, arabic

I'm trying to use this [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) for my work. The same template can be opened and modified in Overleaf using this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/9774978732rmmndjdvrzjt).
The work will be mainly in English/German text, however I would like to be able to add some Arabic "**paragraphs**/**sentences**/**words**/**characters**" to any part of the document. I tried out several solutions suggested in other questions here on **Stackexchange**. But unfortunately none of them worked for this particular template. I just need someone to point out what kind of modifications do I need in order to make this possible?

Please forgive me if the question doesn't look to be appropriate or if the answer is very obvious, I'm just inexperienced latex user.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: There are several solutions depending on your requirements: `babel`, `polyglossia`, `arabxetex`, `arabluatex`, etc. Why doesn't this template work with the applied solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `polyglossia` package to write Arabic.

For that you need XeLaTex.

You also need to disable the `hyperref` package support in the documentclass, as this is loaded at the end, and hyperref must not be loaded after bidi (wich is the RL package that polyglossia loads).

So the changes are:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true,% Set to false to disable coloring links
citecolor=magenta,% The color of citations
linkcolor=red,% The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
urlcolor=mdtRed,% The color of hyperlinks (URLs)
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
        \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
    \setotherlanguage{arabic}
        \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
```

Notice the nohyperref option. The hypersetup is the same as the document class, only loaded before the bidi.

now, anywhere in the document you may use `\textarabic{}` To write in arabic

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Just a follow-up question: The sentence you added to the document was rendered without errors, which is perfect. However Semitic languages read from right to left, but the interpreter rendered it from the left!! Anything can be said on this?

Comment: Ok, I just fixed that using right-alignment `\hfill`, but if there is any better solution, I would be thankful if anybody refer to it.

Comment: The \textarabic is an inline text switch. It assumes the main language is English and adds Arabic from left to right. If you wish to start an Arabic paragraph you need to tell XeLaTeX that the environment is mainly Arabic. This is done using `\begin{Arabic}` and `\end{Arabic}`. I believe this is in the polyglossia manual.